# Insert link in Email body using HTMLBody text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want the text for "How to action notices" become hyperlink.

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: fvs[key][0][1],
cc: "",
subject: "[FOR YOUR ACTION]  Outstanding Tax Mail",
htmlBody: "Dear Vialter,

This is a follow up email on the below list of notices that are still sitting in the Awaiting Second Approval status in OneDMS.
It is essential that we resolve these outstanding items to ensure compliance and maintain an accurate and up-to-date record in OneDMS to manage our clients and Vialto's risk.
If you have already actioned the notice (sent to the taxpayer or sent to file), please go and perform the Second Approval on the notice to move it from the 'Awaiting Second Approval' to 'Final and Published'.
Here is a one pager on how to action notices in OneDMS.
List of notices that you are listed on:
" + messageBody2 + "" + messageBody + "
Kind Regards,
CTA Team ",   // Options: Body (HTML)
name: "",});

I tried to input the URL in the variables, but it seems like it doesnt appear to be a link. I just need to make the text to be a hyperlink to the manual, without having to change the code entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this using `htmlBody` for the entire message and My link will open google.com.

```
function sendEmail() {
  try {
    let notices = ["Notice 1","Notice 2","Notice 3"];
    let subject = "[FOR YOUR ACTION] Outstanding Tax Mail";

    let htmlBody = "<p>Dear Vialter,</p><br><br>";
    htmlBody = htmlBody+"<p>This is a follow up email on the below list of notices that are still sitting in the Awaiting Second Approval status in OneDMS.</p>"
    htmlBody = htmlBody+"<p>It is essential that we resolve these outstanding items to ensure compliance and maintain an accurate and up-to-date record in OneDMS to manage our clients and Vialto's risk.</p>";
    htmlBody = htmlBody+"<p>If you have already actioned the notice (sent to the taxpayer or sent to file), please go and perform the Second Approval on the notice to move it from the 'Awaiting Second Approval' to 'Final and Published'.</p>";
    htmlBody = htmlBody+"<p>Here is a one pager on how to action notices in OneDMS.</p>";
    htmlBody = htmlBody+"<p>List of notices that you are listed on:</p><ul>";
    
    notices.forEach( notice => {
        htmlBody = htmlBody+"<li>"+notice+"</li>";
      }
    )
    htmlBody = htmlBody+'</ul><br><a href="google.com">My link</a>'
    GmailApp.sendEmail("thewized@gmail.com",subject,null,{htmlBody: htmlBody});
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

[image]