# How to embed a hyperlink in the body of an email in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-forms

I found a code that allows me to send emails to specific people based on an answer submitted in a Google Form. That works perfectly fine, but I want to embed a hyperlink to another google form in the email. This is my first time working with code, so I'm not sure how to edit the code properly to let me do that. I specifically want the code to be in between the words "second Form".

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var response = e.namedValues;

  var dropdownSelection = response['Agency'][0];

  var emailSubject = 'Someone has submitted a form';
  

  var questionOrder = [

    'Agency',
    'Staff Name',  
    'Client Name',
    'Zipcode',
    'Email',
    'Phone Number',
    'Services Requested',
    'Client Notes',

  
  ];


  var htmlBody = 'A new referral has been submitted. If you decide to accept the client, please fill out the second Form. Details:\n\n';

  for (var i = 0; i < questionOrder.length; i++) {

    var question = questionOrder[i];

    var answer = response[question] ? response[question][0] : 'N/A';

    htmlBody += question + ': ' + answer + '\n\n';

  }


  var emailMap = {
    'Agency1': 'email1@gmail.com
    'Agency2': 'email2@gmail.com' + "," + 'email3@gmail.com',
    'Agency3': 'email4@gmail.com',
    'Agency4': 'email5@gmail.com',


};

  if (emailMap.hasOwnProperty(dropdownSelection)) {

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailMap[dropdownSelection], emailSubject, htmlBody);
    
  } else {

 Logger.log('Warning: dropdownSelection ' + dropdownSelection + ' not found in emailMap');

  }

}
```

I have tried to use  but the email simply had the code in the body instead of embedding the link.

```
var htmlBody = 'A new referral for your organization has been submitted. If you decide to accept the client, please fill out the "<a href= "https:googleform.com">second Form </a>". Details:\n\n';
```

When I did that, the text "Demographics Form " showed up in the email rather than being embedded.

Comment: Does this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77428335/insert-link-in-email-body-using-htmlbody-text/77432820#77432820) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert link in Email body using HTMLBody text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77428335/insert-link-in-email-body-using-htmlbody-text)